# Retrofit + OkHttp Unexpected Status Line <!DOCType html>

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

For a few months my app was working fine but in a few weeks i get this error sometimes when i do sequential requests. I did not update anything in my app. iOS version off app has no problem but i get this error sometimes especially in my first time requests.

```
02-05 04:45:14.017  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: <!DOCType html>
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.StatusLine.parse(StatusLine.java:73)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:187)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:791)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.access$200(HttpEngine.java:90)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:784)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:645)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:263)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:219)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:192)
            at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.execute(Call.java:79)
            at retrofit.client.OkClient.execute(OkClient.java:53)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
            at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$1.invoke(RestAdapter.java:265)
            at retrofit.RxSupport$2.run(RxSupport.java:55)
            at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-05 04:45:14.017  15972-16249/com.myapp.android D/Retrofit﹕ ---- END ERROR
```

Comment: This is not a retrofit issue, your API is returning an HTML instead of JSON/XML whatever you are expecting. What I suggest if you try to make the same request in a browser rest client and see the response. You should debug and find the exact url and field/query/header being passed in retrofit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused by a problem in connection reuse. Do you know the response code and headers of the previous response? OkHttp is interpreting that as having no body, and the server disagrees.

Comment: Previous response header is 401. can this cause the problem?

Comment: Actually i got the problem i think. I have a background call and i call it about 3-4 times in background and it's response is 401. when i close this api call i do not get this error. is it possible? @JesseWilson

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @savepopulation . Even I have the same problem. Response is fine when DefaultHttpClient is used but, when I try with OkHttp then it throws some DOCTYPE in response.

Comment: Actually my problem was about serverside. When i call api an internal error occurs and api cannot return a successfull http response to me

Answer (score 1):

Setting header value to,

```
@Headers("Connection:close")
```

worked for me.

Comment: Yes this is a solution but i'm not sure about if it's right to use. I think server side should decide to close or resume the connection.

Comment: Thank you very much. I spent a day searching for the solution to this issue: HTTP FAILED: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line:  HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
2023